# Why do we need Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring

Hi I am new to String and is reading the article by Martin Fowler: http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

He gave an example of MovieLister using a MovieFinder for finding movies. In this example, he first provided the code:

```
class MovieLister...
    private MovieFinder finder;
    public MovieLister() {
        finder = new ColonDelimitedMovieFinder("movies1.txt");
    }
}
```

He pointed out that you can't give MovieLister to your friend for reuse, unless your friend uses the same MovieFinder implementation and put the movies in the same txt file.

Yes, of course, this is NOT the way you write a component with a hope that someone can reuse it. Instead, as he progressed, you should write:

```
class MovieLister...
    public MovieLister(MovieFinder finder) {
        this.finder = finder;       
    }
}
```

Yes, that is better. Now your friend can take over your MovieLister and plug in his own code. To me, the story is complete. I miss the point why you need a Spring framework to inject the dependency. The dependency is injected to MovieLister by your friend's code. Full stop. All the Spring setup is equivalent to simply implement the MovieFinder interface and make such a call:

```
MovieFinder myMovieFinder = new MyMovieFinderImpl();
MovieLister myMovieLister = new MovieLister(myMovieFinder);
```

Simple, easy. I know you hard code the creation of the MyMovieFinderImpl instance in your code. But what's the point of moving this to XML but bringing so much other stuff? Since when programmers become so scared of compiling code and prefer changing XML without compiling to get everything done? I am sorry but I think I just miss the point. Every program uses dependency inject, decades ago. But in the old days, dependency is injected by programs using a library, or a DOS command line, or a GUI. Why now we need yet another way as to inject dependency?

Thank you.

Updated:

Well, many of you guys brought annotation up. In my sallow understanding of Spring, I may feel more comfortable using XML rather than annotation. At least there is a central place listing how the dependency is, in a way that is easier to understand. With annotation, no such central place. Instead, just magic happening. Wanna know what is passed in as the parameter? Go figure it out yourself and good luck. Yes, I know there are smart IDE plugins help  navigate the code. But why we make one thing complicated in the first place and celebrate another thing that helps make our life easier? The truth that annotation makes code harder to browse and understand so people create IDE plugins for this is obvious enough that we may create unnecessary things in the first place, isn't it?

Comment: In such a simple case you're right. There is no point to doing DI with a framework. But when you get to the level of systems with hundreds of APIs and implementations (not all of which may be known until runtime, and implementations that have their own dependencies, who have their own dependencies... Try keeping it straight without Spring or some other framework. It can be done, but it can become a royal pain very quickly. Personally, I'd recommend JSR330's annotations, and looking into Guice or Dagger as a framework.

Comment: This is definitely a good question. I came to the conclusion that *Inversion of control* and *dipendencies injection* are really marketing buzzwords by Springsource...

Comment: @Raffaele How do you figure that?! The term predates SpringSource, Spring, and Java. IIRC it came out of Smalltalk, like so many other useful things. The idea that Spring or SpringSource invented the idea is ridiculous. It may have been *popularized* recently, but the term came before it, and the pattern came long before that.

Comment: @DaveNewton I voted your answer just when you posted it, even if you still don't really tell **why do we need**. My previous comment is very short (it's a comment, not a paper) and what I mean is simply that everybody achieves the same purpose in one way or another, but only Springsource puts IoC on its homepage, and this is because once you give it a name, you create a market for your product. The backing idea is not revolutionary, is not special, and that's why a newcomer can't figure out why this thing has a name and is heavily advertised throughout the documentation

Comment: @Raffaele Guice, PicoContainer, Avalon (defunct), Plexus, and several other lessor-known frameworks also use IoC on their homepages. You are correct that the concept has been around forever (ever since *I* can remember, anyway), and that Spring popularized it, but they're certainly not the first to name it, or push it, or deliver it.

Comment: @DaveNewton, agree. I just wanted to give my advice because the newcomer, after reading chapters of documentation, always feels 
*"I must be missing something, I absolutely don't see the point"*. Is my humble opinion that if you put this in perspective (in this case *business perspective*), so that the developer doesn't expect the *atomic bomb* anymore, he sooner stops to re-read the doc and starts coding :)

Comment: I like that updated part. Annotations for a beginner like me complicate things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the "old days" code was written as in the first example.

Spring *is* a library, which you say is one of the ways it was done in the "old days".

Implementations were rarely specified on the command line or via a GUI. Multiple implementations of the same functionality weren't needed as often because (a) systems were rarely as complex as they are today, (b) they didn't need to interoperate with other systems the way they do today, and (c) deep testing was implemented far less often.

What's "so much other stuff"? Spring is segregated; you can bring in only what you need.

Why did you ignore configuration via annotations?

The purpose is to use a generic, localized, known, standard mechanism. It is ludicrous to say that "every program used dependency injection, decades ago." I programmed decades ago, across a pretty wide swath of languages, and while we did similar things, we all had our own implementations, with varying levels of sophistication, and wildly varying levels of success.

Is Spring *necessary* for DI/IoC? No, and a host of other DI frameworks attest to this. Is it a well-known, essentially-standard way of doing it? Yep.

Answer (score 7):

Do not confuse the principle (DI) with *one* implementation (Spring).

If you like DI but prefer doing the wiring in your code: Use Google Guice.

If you like DI but prefer doing the wiring in your code *and* optionally XML then use CDI (from the Java EE track of things).

If you like DI and love XML (or must change the behaviour of your application by reconfiguring things) then just use Spring.

If you do not like DI then ... ask another question.

It's good to have several implementations of the same principle.

Comment: Unless you hardcode dependency before compiling, you always need DI. I can rarely find any serious program that doesn't use DI at all. DI is everywhere if you want your code to be reusable. It is just interesting to see people go that far and spend that much effort to address a thing that exists all the way. That much effort must has some significant reason. Maybe the simple tutorial example doesn't reveal something...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you have only two classes, it is simpler and easier to do the "dependency injection" manually. But if you have lots of classes, it is easier and more flexible if a framework (such as Spring) finds out for you the correct initialization and injection order.

BTW, in recent Spring versions you don't need to mess (much) with XML, you can declare the dependencies with annotations.